# add multiple classes in nintex form inputs

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I have a nintex form

I have a input textbox which already has a class and I want to add a class to it

[image]

How can I add one more css class here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we need to enter the list of class names separated by a space

example

```
nf-form-input hiddenclass
```